# Suggested edit using unreleased language feature

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

[This suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8226439), changes some C# code to replace a try-catch block with the new `?.` operator. I've seen this called the "safe navigation operator" or "null-conditional operator".

My understanding is that this feature will be included in C# 6.0, but does not exist in the current language version.

On the one hand, that code won't compile in current C# tools, so I think I should reject the edit. On the other hand, it is cleaner code, and should represent best practice once the new version is released, so I feel conflicted.

What's the priority? The edit *will be* better code, but it is not better right now.

Comment: Unless the question was *specific to 6.0*, I would reject that edit even *after* the new version was released, as it doesn't actually mention the difference. If it had been *"note that from 6.0 you will be able to do ... instead"* that would be fine (assuming it does the same thing) even prior to the release.

Comment: The edit has now been rejected.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Even if that code would have compiled, I personally think that the edit deviates from the authors intent.  It's completely changing the code (the comment even says "No need to add the cost of excpetions when you could just use the Safe Navigation Operator").  This is a great comment, or even alternate answer but not an edit.

Because it is a rather drastic change (a change in programming paradigms from explicit exception handling to guarding against null) the edit should be rejected.